# Google API Nodejs client 5.2.0 won't install its dependencies

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, google-api, google-api-client

Today I switched to version 5.2.0 but npm (seems to) fails to install its dependencies.

Running my project I get "dependency swig is missing".

If I manually install it (npm install swig) I get "dependency js-beautify is missing".

If I manually install it (npm install js-beautify) I get "Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open './templates/api-endpoint.js'"

Am I missing something or 5.2.0 is just broken?

Thank You.

Answer (score 2):

I've been having this issue as well. A temporary fix is to go inside of googleapis folder, and run npm install in there. For some reason I've been having trouble getting googlepais to download its dependencies.

Comment: I had the same problem with https://www.npmjs.com/package/googleapis, this fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete the `node_modules` folder and run `npm install` once more. I've had this issue once and that fixes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Well, seems this issue was fixed.

[5.2.0 is messed up - missing dependencies, missing files](https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client/issues/560)